# elasticsearch phrase searching

Tags: json, search, nosql, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I have a document in elastic search that looks like...

```
{
    "items":
    [
        "ONE BLAH BLAH BLAH TWO BLAH BLAH BLAH THREE",
        "FOUR BLAH BLAH BLAH FIVE BLAH BLAH BLAH SIX"
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to search for this document with a phrase query like...

```
{
    "match_phrase" : {
        "items" : "ONE TWO THREE"
    }
}
```

So that it will match regardless of the words in-between. The words also need to be in that order. I realise that this could be achieved via the `slop` property, however when I was experimenting with that it seemed to wrap if the slop was more than the words in-between what I was searching on and as this is an indeterminate amount of words I don't think slop would be suitable. Also I need to only search per item in the array, so...

```
{
    "match_phrase" : {
        "items" : "ONE TWO SIX"
    }
}
```

Wont match this document as `SIX` is in a different item in the array to `ONE` and `TWO`.

So my question is, is this possible through elasticsearch or will I have to make an array of objects and use a nested query to search on them?

Answer (score 12):

It can be done using [Span Near Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/span-near-query.html). I am not sure what went wrong in your experiments, and what you mean by "wrapping". I can only guess that, perhaps, you specified "in_order":"false" and your query was just ignoring the order of terms. Could you provide an example?

To avoid query spanning multiple items, you need to increase "gap" between items in mapping by using "position_offset_gap" property. Here is an example:

```
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/slop-test"
echo
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/slop-test" -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }    
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "items" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "position_offset_gap": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
echo
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/slop-test/doc/1" -d '{
  "items":
  [
      "ONE BLAH BLAH BLAH TWO BLAH BLAH BLAH THREE",
      "FOUR BLAH BLAH BLAH FIVE BLAH BLAH BLAH SIX"
  ]
}'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/slop-test/_refresh"
echo
curl "localhost:9200/slop-test/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query" : {
    "span_near" : {
      "clauses" : [
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "one" } },
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "two" } },
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "three" } }
      ],
      "slop" : 40,
      "in_order" : true
    }
  }
}'
echo
curl "localhost:9200/slop-test/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query" : {
    "span_near" : {
      "clauses" : [
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "one" } },
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "two" } },
        { "span_term" : { "items" : "six" } }
      ],
      "slop" : 40,
      "in_order" : true
    }
  }
}'
echo
```